# Get DialogResult from Public Sub (Module)

Tags: .net, vb.net, public, byval

I don't know what keyword to search.

This is on a module in my app.

```
Public Sub msgYNC(ByVal result As DialogResult)
    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save and continue?", "RM Farms Confirmation", _
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
End Sub
```

Now I want to use it on a form. So when I click on <kbd>Confirm</kbd> :

```
Dim result As DialogResult
    msgYNC(result)
    If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        'yes
    ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        'n
    ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        'ca
    End If
```

But it doesn't return me anything.. I don't get a response. I am not sure how to code this, can you pinpoint what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should be quite simple. Don't use byval in your Sub, use `byref`

```
Public Sub msgYNC(ByRef result As DialogResult)
    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save and continue?", 
                             "RM Farms Confirmation", _
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
End Sub
```

could you try this?

Altough you could use the following structure (if you only want to show a messagebox in your `sub-method msgYNC`)

```
    Select Case MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
            'Do something
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
            'Do something else
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
            'Cancel something
        Case Else
            'Do something unusefull
    End Select
```

Comment: thanks, worked. wait for 5 minutes to accept the answer. Now I think I know why, is it because the value of `result` is in the sub?

Comment: Thats correct ,the key sentence to remember is: ´byval´ passes along the value (without referencing the object), ´byref´passes along a reference to an object and its value.